# num2str sets a constant width for integer formatting

Tags: string, matlab, formatting, integer

I am using `num2str` to print an array of integers. My problem is that the format `%d,` (notice no flag or field width) doesn't yield a comma-separated list of values as I would expect.

Instead, it seems that all elements are forced to the same width by introducing spaces. I would like to get rid of these spaces. For example:

```
>> num2str(randi(10,1,10),'%d,')
7, 8,10,10, 2, 2, 7, 1, 6, 6,

>> num2str(randi(10,1,10),'%d,')
9,5,4,7,8,6,4,2,6,3,
```

In the first example, you can see that all elements have a width of 2 -- this is the largest width among all elements, but I would prefer the output list to be compact: `7,8,10,10,2,2,7,1,6,6,`. In the second example, the largest width is 1, and there are no spaces introduced. I don't understand why Matlab would force all elements to have equal field length.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain?

Comment: Perhaps the example could be better, i.e. why two examples instead of stating what result you produced and what result you desired and specify the differences between them? I.e.: I use this line of code ``num2str(randi(10,1,10),'%d,')`` and get this output ``7, 8,10,10, 2, 2, 7, 1, 6, 6,`` where you can see white spaces between the 1-digit-numbers and the delimiter, but i want to have ``7,8,10,10,2,2,7,1,6,6,``. How can i get this? Also to reproduce the problem you need to be lucky to draw a ``10``, it would have been better to draw numbers from 1 to 15 maybe.

Comment: @Nras, is it better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num2str` computes the max of the vector, and pads with white space numbers that have less digits (type `edit num2str` in the command window to see the source code).

Try `sprintf` instead,

```
sprintf('%d,', randi(1000,1,10))
```

Comment: Thanks :) That's what I wanted